# Ruby on Rails / Active Record / MYSQL - Group by and order by a string attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model/object with a date attribute as a string, and this code:

```
Model.all.group_by { |t| t.date }
```

This gives me a hash like {"06/11/2013"=>[object 5, object 17], "07/18/2013"=>[...], "05/02/2013"=>[...]} (with all the model's attributes in there).

It doesn't seem to sort by date at all this way. In fact it pretty much jumps around.

Is there a way for me to add an

```
.order('date ASC')
```

on here somehow, so that the hash goes in order by date?

Comment: when it is a date in a string you may change the datatype. otherwise typecast the field before sort. how - depends on your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do

```
Model.all.group_by{ |t| t.date }.sort
```

then you will get sorted result but it will be double array. You can convert this array to hash or use accordingly.

Comment: This worked. But its in reverse order than I wanted it?

Comment: This did the trick: `Model.all.group_by{ |t| t.date }.sort{ |x,y| y <=> x}` - But I'm wondering if this is the best way or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use T-SQL CAST or CONVERT.

With respect to your database (MySQL?) I think this will work:

```
Model.all.order('CAST(date AS TIMESTAMP) asc')

or

Model.all.order('CAST(created_at AS DATETIME) asc')
```

But your string format shall be convertable, otherwise you cannot cast type

Comment: I don't think you quite understood the question. I was asking how to combine the grouping and the sorting. This doesn't take into account the grouping at all. The above solution worked.